# Organizing fixture preferences for plugin tests

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

To test an eclipse application I have written a test suite that dynamically discovers available test cases at runtime by searching for test projects stored in a subfolder of a given bundle, looking like this:

```
my.plugin
  src/      
  fixtures/ 
    p1/     
    p2/
```

Each fixture is a fully fledged eclipse project. At runtime my suite discovers `p1` and `p2` and creates a Test for each. Then each test imports its fixture into the workspace on setup, then runs the actual test code and deletes the fixture on teardown. So far this works great, I just dump another fixture to add a new test. No need to write more code for new tests. Yay!

My problem is now that all this runs against a clean workspace with default preferences. What if some of my fixtures need specific preference settings in order to be useful? I somehow would need to provide those custom preferences with the fixture and make sure they are loaded in the test setup for the fixture and restore the default workbench preferences on teardown. What's the best way to do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I would do something like this:

Let the user choose (in the settings) if the test should be run in a clean workspace or not. If not, just use the current one, so the users can apply settings there. I think this is reasonable, as test running is usually done in the same workspace as the actual project to be tested.

You can access the current workspace by calling `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use project settings only, then the solution is simple.  Just create a .settings folder in each project and populate the appropriate `org.foo.bundle.name.prefs` file.

Things get more complicated if you want to have workspace settings.  I would recommend looking at the `org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IScopeContext` APIs.  Eclipse uses a hierarchical approach to providing preferences.  You can set a hierarchy of scopes, eg- Default, workspace, and project scopes.  Each scope has one or more nodes and each node has a set of key-value pairs.

So for example, you generally will look up a preference, say the source level compiler property inside a particular project.  Here are the steps that this goes through:

1. Create the scope hierarchy, typically the root is default, then workspace, then the project.
2. Get the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` node from the bottom scope.
3. Ask the node for a value associated with a key.
4. If this node has a value, then return it, otherwise go to the node from the next scope.
5. If none of the scopes contain the key, then return some default value.

Your best bet for doing this work simply and not using internal Eclipse APIs is to use a `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore` instance.  You will create the lookup hierarchy of IPreferenceStores that you want to get your preferences from and one of them will be a custom IPreferenceStore created by you that will supply the extra preferences for your project.

Now, of course you need to ensure that all places that require these custom preferences are able to have a custom ChainedPreferenceStore passed in.

Comment: The org.foo.bundle.name.prefs file is the one that's created by ProjectScope?

Comment: Project scope creates the files in .settimgs.  InstanceScope creates files in workspace/.metadata/.plugings/org.eclipse.core.runtime/*.prefs